# Find $x$ if $\int^x_{\log 2}\frac{dy}{e^y-1}=\frac{\pi}{6}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> If $\int^x_{\log 2}\dfrac{dy}{e^y-1}=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$, then find x

Set $e^y-1=t\implies e^y.dy=dt$
$$
\int^x_{\log 2}\dfrac{dy}{e^y-1}=\int^x_{\log 2}\dfrac{e^y.dy}{e^y(e^y-1)}=\int_1^{e^x-1}\frac{dt}{t(t+1)}=\int_1^{e^x-1}\Big[\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t+1}dt\Big]\\
=\bigg[\log\dfrac{t}{t+1}\bigg]_1^{e^x-1}=\log\frac{e^x-1}{e^x}-\log\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\pi}{6}
$$

I think something is not right, the solution given in my reference is $x=\log 4$, so what's going wrong with my attempt here ?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the correct answer in the reference?  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F%28e%5Ey-1%29+y%3Dln%282%29+to+ln%284%29) says that $\int_{\ln 2}^{\ln 4} \frac{dy}{e^y-1} = \ln\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$.

Comment: my reference can have mistakes sometimes, not that trust worthy.

Comment: $x=\log 4$ is certainly wrong. Your approach is correct, now you just have to solve for $x$ the equation $\log\left(\frac{e^x - 1}{e^x}\right) - \log\frac{1}{2} =\frac\pi6$.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp Thanx. and I think it is $\sqrt{e^y-1}$ in the denominator, then everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q=e^{-x}$.
Then
$$\begin{align}
\ln(1-q)&=\frac\pi6-\ln2\\
1-q&=\frac12\exp\frac\pi6\\
q&=1-\frac12\exp\frac\pi6\\
\Rightarrow x&=-\ln\left(1-\frac12\exp\frac\pi6\right).
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{\ln 2}^{x} \frac{dy}{e^y-1} =\ln(1-e^{-x})-\ln (1/2)=\frac{\pi}{6} \implies x=-\ln(1-\frac{e^{-\pi/6}}{2}).$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $e^y-1↦t$
$$\int_{\ln\left(2\right)}^{x}\frac{dy}{e^{y}-1}=\ln\left(e^{x}-1\right)-x+\ln\left(2\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

then since $x=\ln e^{x}$ follows:

$$\ln\left(\frac{e^{x}-1}{e^{x}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}-\ln\left(2\right)$$
$$1-e^{-x}=e^{\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\ln\left(2\right)\right)}$$

$$\color{green} {\boxed{ x=-\ln\left(1-e^{\frac{\pi}{6}-\ln\left(2\right)}\right)}}$$